# sportsRunning and sportsWalking

Tags: beginner, html, react.js, jsx

There are two functions, `sportsRunning` and `sportsWalking`, that will render different text. For this, I am using an `if` condition at the bottom to display corresponding div:

```
{sportsDescription.sportsDate && sportsDescription.sportsDate.length > 0 && sportsDescription.sportsDate !== '2199-01-01' ?
                this.sportsWalking() : this.sportsRunning()}`
```

Can you tell me how I can refactor the code?

```
sportsRunning() {
    const sportsFire = this.props.profile.firstName;
    return (
        <div className="sports-table action-shadow">
            <h4>{`Want some advice${sportsFire && sportsFire.length > 0 ? `, ${sportsFire}` : ''}?`}</h4>
            <p>Stay focused by setting a target date for completion of your sports.</p>
            <div className="secondary-links section_content">
                <a href="javascript:;" onClick={this.editHandler}>Set Target Date</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

sportsWalking() {
    const sportsFire = this.props.profile.firstName;
    return (
        <div className="sports-table action-shadow">
            <h4>{`Want a helpful tip${sportsFire && sportsFire.length > 0 ? `, ${sportsFire}` : ''}?`}</h4>
            <p>Add some momentum to your account by setting up automatic recurring deposits.</p>
            <div className="secondary-links section_content">
                <a href="javascript:;" onClick={this.editHandler}>Set Up Automatic Deposits</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

render() {
    const {sportsDescription, data} = this.props;
    const sportsAmount = parseFloat(sportsDescription.sportsAmount);
    const accumulatedAmount = data.summary.total || 0;

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="content-box action-shadow">
                {
                    sportsDescription.error ?
                        this.renderProgressError() :
                        this.renderProgress({
                            accumulatedAmount,
                            sportsAmount
                        })
                }
                <div className="section_content">
                    <h2>Your Goal Progress</h2>
                    <p>You have accumulated <strong className={accumulatedAmount >= 0 ? null : 'negative'}>
                        {moneyFormat(accumulatedAmount)}</strong> towards your sports of <strong>
                        {moneyFormat(sportsAmount)}</strong>.
                    </p>
                    {
                        sportsDescription.sportsDate && sportsDescription.sportsDate.length > 0 &&
                        sportsDescription.sportsDate !== '2199-01-01' && this.renderGoalDate(sportsDescription.sportsDate)
                    }
                    <div className="secondary-links section_content">
                        <a href="javascript:;" onClick={this.editHandler}>Edit Goal Details</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {sportsDescription.sportsDate && sportsDescription.sportsDate.length > 0 && sportsDescription.sportsDate !== '2199-01-01' ?
                this.sportsWalking() : this.sportsRunning()}
        </div>
    );
```

Comment: Welcome to CR! Looks like the formatting is a bit off. Take a look at the [editing help](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/editing-help) page for all the information you need to fix the formatting of your post.

Comment: Can you tell us, what you think could be refactored? Because both functions return different texts, but with the same layout.. If the layout will not change you could create pureRenderComponent ala `(props) => (<div></div>)` But if the structure will change at any point, then its fine to keep it separately, then you will have less trouble to customize it

Comment: @webdeb layout will not change...but your solution is confusing for me...can you updated in my code

Comment: @user3854268 check out my answer

Answer (score 1):

This is what I mean with pureRenderComponent:

```
const SportsMoving = ({editHandler, sportsDescription, ...props }) => {

   const isRunning = sportsDescription.sportsDate && sportsDescription.sportsDate.length > 0 && sportsDescription.sportsDate !== '2199-01-01';
   const sportFire = props.profile.firstName || "";

   return (
        <div className="sports-table action-shadow">
            <h4>
            {
              isRunning 
                ? `Want some advice ${sportFire}?` 
                : `Want a helpful tip ${sportsFire}?`
            }
            </h4>
            <p>
            {
              isRunning 
                ? "Stay focused by setting a target date for completion of your sports."
                : "Add some momentum to your account by setting up automatic recurring deposits."
            }
            </p>
            <div className="secondary-links section_content">
               <a href="javascript:;" onClick={editHandler}>
               {
                 isRunning
                   ? "Set Target Date"
                   : "Set Up Automatic Deposits"
               }
               </a>
            </div>
        </div>
   )
}
```

now in your parentComponent you can use it like so:

```
     ...
     </div>
     <SportsMoving editHandler={this.editHandler} ...props />
</div>
```